# Make the reply count larger in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to make the reply count larger in WordPress. See the image below:

[image]

Here is the website: https://thisisyourworld.net/an-ethic-of-virtue-and-the-modern-condition-part-i/#comment-55.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the correct element (you can even get a selector automatically by using Chrome's built-in developer tools, afterwards you can set size by using the font-size property, like so:

```css
#theSelector {
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

Obviously #theSelector has to be swapped for the appropriate selector for the reply counter element. You can then put the block at the bottom of the style.css file of your currently active theme.